# Review Queue (Late Answers) suddenly has 300+ old items

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Late Answers queue has > 300 items in it, all seem to be years old.  Something like this happened awhile back.  I imagine it will go away on its own, but pointing it out in case someone wants to take a look at it.

Comment: See [Jon Ericson's answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/267080/208518) for some background on this.

Comment: So...what's going on is that they raised the reputation bar to 50 (i.e., to capture all the answers from folks who can't comment), and now our backlog queue is 300+, and we should plow through it?

Comment: @inkista Could be ServerFault — queue over there is over 3k.

Comment: @mattdm Oh, ouch.

Comment: Related: http://jericson.github.io/2015/10/11/late_answers.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More [Custodian](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/104/custodian), [Reviewer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/90/reviewer), and [Steward](https://photo.stackexchange.com/help/badges/105/steward) badges for all!

Comment: Aww... we can only 20 at a time... :D

Comment: And I'm now getting complained at by the system for not having voted on questions :-)

Comment: Ugh, this seems to have resulted in several people going through and clicking "No action needed!" on most of the queue, which is unfortunate, because a lot of those _could_ have used some improvement.

Comment: Not actually taking time to really review is a good way for some to encounter a review ban...